# event handler for initiation of google street view

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make an application with google maps API. I want a function to be called when the user goes into street view. How would I create an event handler for when the street view is initiated?

Comment: How does the user get into street view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should really go into the documentation before asking this question. Anyway, if you pay attention to the [StreetViewPanorama class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama) doc you will find something like

> visible_changed
>
> Arguments:  None
>
> This event is fired when the panorama's visibility changes. The
>   visibility is changed when the Pegman is dragged onto the map, the
>   close button is clicked, or setVisible() is called.

So probably using something like

```
var your_panorama = map.getStreetView()
```

you can then add a listener to the 'visible_changed' event. Calling the getVisible() method on your panorama should also help detect if you are actually in streetView mode. From there you can have your app behave accordingly. Play around with it and I am sure you'll be able to attain what you want.